# Wordpress VIP realpath Alternative?

Tags: mysql, wordpress.com-hosting, paths

I am running a scan for a site to be proposed to wp vip. The only error I am getting is :

> Warning: Returns canonicalized absolute pathname header-payroll.php
>   require_once realpath(dirname(**FILE**)). '/header.php';

What would be the fix for this. I believe I would need an alternative for "realpath"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "wp vip" wants or needs, but you should be loading files by means of [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template), [`site_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url), or [`home_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) and I am guessing that using one or more of those is what the "scan" wants. It is hard to say exactly which since you posted only the error and not the source that goes with the error.